# If dentro de um success no ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu faço a requisição, recebo o valor certo, mas na hora da verificação não da certo

```
                $.ajax({
                    url:'includes/checkCPF.inc.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    type:'POST',        
                    data:{cpf:cpf},
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    if(data == "V")
                    {
                        alert("b");   
                        $(".cpf").addClass("ShadowRed");
                        $(".cpf").focus();
                        return
                    }
                 });
```

php:

```
<?php
include_once '../acesso.php';
$cpf = $_POST["cpf"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login_usuario WHERE CpfUsuario = '$cpf'";
$pedido = $conn->query($sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($pedido) != 0)
{
    echo "V";
}
else
{
    echo "F";
}
```

Comment: O alert retorna o que?

Comment: V ou F com base no if do php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O retorno do Ajax com `echo` para receber uma string pode retornar espaços em branco nas extremidades da string, e isso fará diferença no `if` que irá diferenciar a letra `V` de um `V` com espaços antes e/ou depois.

Limpe estes espaços retornados no `data` com o método `.trim()`:

```
if(data.trim() == "V")
```

Também faltou fechar o `success:` com chaves `}`:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'includes/checkCPF.inc.php',
   method:'POST',
   type:'POST',        
   data:{cpf:cpf},
   success:function(data){
      alert(data);
      if(data.trim() == "V")
      {
         alert("b");   
         $(".cpf").addClass("ShadowRed");
         $(".cpf").focus();
         return;
      }
   } ← FECHAR AQUI
});
```

Comment: VC SALVOU MINHA VIDA!!!

Comment: Bem usado o método `trim()`. +1

Comment: estava com este problema de espaço vazio! obrigado pela resposta